# Using Non-Capturing Groups in MySQL REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

For some reason I can't seem to use non-capturing groups in MySQL. Is there a way to use them in a MySQL `REGEXP`?

For non-capturing groups in PHP's PCRE implementation, I use this syntax:

```
(?:[PATTERN])
```

Comment: Adapted from Andrej Ludinovskov’s comment-answer from 2011, which should be deleted: as the [MySQL 5.1 regexp docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) show, parentheses form a group but do not capture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Groups in MySQL regular expressions are not capturing groups, since capturing groups in SQL wouldn't make much sense... well, not without the addition of syntax to support using the captured substrings.  So it doesn't support the `(?: )` syntax, since this syntax is pointless within MySQL -- the groups *already* don't capture.

So, `([PATTERN])` IS a non-capturing group.

Comment: Quick fix for non-capturing groups in `pattern`: `REPLACE(pattern, '?:', '');`

Comment: @Nae This is not a robust solution; it can remove more than just non-capturing specifiers.