# Mysql filter json data value range

Tags: mysql, json, range

This one is bit complicated than sinmple range in mysql , 
my field data is `{"id":"15","value":"1200"}`  and I can find it by ,

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `my_table` 
WHERE  `my_field` 
REGEXP  '{"id":"15","value":"1200"}'
```

but what I need is the range for the value

so I need to look for range between 1000 > 2000 and field with json value 1200 should match. 
I cant redo the output with php because it will eat up the resource , so please if it is possible within Mysql without me processing the data trough php on return

any help is appreciated!

**SOLUTION TO ANYONE !**

**LC** gave us very nice solution

```
REGEXP '{"id":"15","value":"(1[0-9][0-9][0-9]|2000)"}'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My knee-jerk reaction is to say "stop storing more than one value in a single column", but if you *have* to do it that way and you have regex power, use it (untested):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `my_table` 
WHERE `my_field` REGEXP '{"id":"15","value":"(1[0-9][0-9][0-9]|2000)"}'
```

Keep in mind, there's no way to optimize this query using indexes so you are stuck with examining every row in `my_table`.

Comment: im getting  Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Comment: got it!  need dot . infront ?

Comment: Sorry, was missing the `:` in the `(?:` for the non-capturing group. But no, you shouldn't need a dot in front, and that would probably make it interpret the curly-brace as a repetition operator.

Comment: for m eit works only if there is . or : INfont of ?  not after

Comment: Right. Non-capturing groups mean nothing in mysql because there's no place to return it, so all groups are non-capturing and the `(?:` syntax is not implemented. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119338/using-non-capturing-groups-in-mysql-regexp