# Match optional end of line

Tags: mysql, regex

Hey I want to use a regular expression in MySQL to match rows.
It needs to match rows where a the pattern ends with anything that's not a digit or the end of the line.

This pattern works in Ruby `/download:223(?:[\D]|$)/`
In MySQL it doesn't match. I'm guessing it doesn't allow for optional matching of eol.

```
SELECT id FROM stories WHERE body REGEXP 'download:223(?:[\D]|$)'
```

I need to match the following  (quotes just for clarity):

```
"download:223"
"download:223*"
"download:223 something"
"download:223 more text"
```

But NOT the following (again quotes just for clarity):

```
"download:2234"
"download:2234 more text"
"download:2234*"
"download:2234* even more"
```

Thanks!

Comment: With end-of-line, you maybe mean end-of-phrase (`$`) ?

Comment: yeh $ (end of line) as apposed to \z (end of string)

Comment: Only if multiline is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
"download:223([^0-9]|$)"
```

**MySQL regex engine doesn't support \D, \d etc.**

Comment: In my ignorance i assumed they were supported, thank you! Sorted

Answer (score 1):

Non-capturing groups are not supported in MySQL regexes.  The rest should be fine.  It definitely supports $ matching the end of string.  Also, \D is not supported, but you can use [^0-9]

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM stories WHERE body REGEXP 'download:223([^0-9]|$)'
```

MySQL groups don't capture, so supporting non-capturing groups is unnecessary.

Reference source:
[Using Non-Capturing Groups in MySQL REGEXP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119338/using-non-capturing-groups-in-mysql-regexp)

Comment: Thanks for the info, that doesn't match anything

Comment: Ahh I see you've changed your answer about \D. Thank you very much for your help.